# External exception C0000006 al iniciar Embarcadero Delphi 2010

Tags: delphi-2010

Trabajo a diario con Delphi 2010 y hoy, al arrancar el IDE, me sale el error:

> External exception C0000006 y se cierra el IDE.

¿Alguien podría indicarme qué puede haber pasado? Esta mañana funcionaba sin problemas.

Comment: ¿Corres el Delphi desde una unidad extraíble o similares? ¿Tienes problemas con el disco?

Comment: O quizás desde la red?

Comment: Bienvenido a [stackoverflow en español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour), puede que le interese leer esto, puede tratar de mejorar su pregunta mirando este link. Para mas información consulte el siguiente enlace. Saludos.